# ¿Qué pasa si no se colocan estos caracteres juntos?

Tags: c, archivo, formato

Hoy he tenido una duda, y he estado buscando por Internet, pero no he encontrado nada.

Al terminar una línea en un fichero, se introducen los caracteres `CR LF` (Retorno de carro y salto de línea).

Mi pregunta es ¿qué pasaría si eliminásemos el `CR`, y dejásemos solo el `LF`?
¿Cómo se puede poner solo el `LF` en C si el `CR`?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### El caracter de retorno de carro (CR) (0x0D, \r)

Mueve el cursor al principio de la línea sin avanzar a la línea siguiente. Este caracter se utiliza como caracter de nueva línea en los sistemas operativos *Commodore y Early Macintosh (OS-9 y versiones anteriores)*.

### El caracter Line Feed (LF) (0x0A, \n)

Mueve el cursor hacia abajo a la siguiente línea sin volver al principio de la línea. Este caracter se utiliza como carácter de nueva línea en sistemas basados ​​en *UNIX (Linux, Mac OSX, etc.)*

### La secuencia de fin de línea (CR LF) (0x0D 0x0A, \r \n)

Es en realidad dos caracteres ASCII, una combinación de los caracteres CR y LF. Mueve el cursor a la siguiente línea y al principio de esa línea. Este carácter se utiliza como un carácter de nueva línea en la mayoría de los demás sistemas operativos que no son Unix, incluidos *Microsoft Windows, Symbian OS y otros*.

Comment: ¿Symbian? O. M. G. 

Comment: La diferencia de usar \n o \r\n, se puede ver de forma muy clara sobre todo cuando desarrollas en Windows pero el servidor es Linux. Claramente Git tiene un comando para convertir estos saltos CRLF a simplemente LF y viceversa llamado autocrlf.

Answer (score 1):

Estos caracteres se pueden añadir dentro de las cadenas con secuencias de escape:

- `"Una cadena con CR LF.\r\n"`
- `"Una cadena solo con CR.\r"`
- `"Una cadena solo con LF.\n"`

Cómo se visualice luego ese texto dependerá del programa concreto, no del sistema operativo en sí.

Lo más habitual es que los editores de texto traten las tres opciones de forma idéntica, aunque, por poner un ejemplo, el Notepad de Windows sólo creará una línea nueva si encuentra CRLF. Si abre un archivo que utiliza solo LF, lo mostrará en una única línea.